# MySQL : Making two table data merge with the given column and same data

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I have data from two table. The column looks like this:

> b_1,b_2,b_3,rule,name

And the other table columns are:

> rule,name,a_1,a_2,a_3

And the resulting table that I would like is:

> b_1,b_2,b_3,rule,name,a_1,a_2,a_3

Example data:

```
b_1,b_2,b_3,rule,name
ab,sd,ed,mine,abhi
gh,jk,ka,nice,sid

rule,name,a_1,a_2,a_3
mine,abhi,qw,er,rt
nice,sid,zx,zx,cv
```

And the resulting data that I need is:

```
b_1,b_2,b_3,rule,name,a_1,a_2,a_3
ab,sd,ed,mine,abhi,qw,er,rt 
gh,jk,ka,nice,sid,zx,zx,cv
```

I have tried this queries:

```
Select b_1,b_2,b_3,b.rule,b.name,a_1,a_2,a_3 from T1 a INNER JOIN T2 b ON b.rule=a.rule and b.name=a.name;

Select b_1,b_2,b_3,b.rule,b.name,a_1,a_2,a_3 from T1 a LEFT JOIN T2 b ON b.rule=a.rule and b.name=a.name;
```

P.S:

Table T1 has 31465 rows.

Table T2 has 31465 rows.

So even Table T3 should also contain 31465 rows.

Both tables have redundant rows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first select you wrote seems the right one if you want ONLY records that are in both tables with same name and rule. Haven't you obtained the output you expected?
If you want all records from T1 and records from T2 if exist, then the second select should be fine, but you have to select a.name, a.rule instead of b.name, b.rule

Comment: No, i didn't get the expected output. The total rows I got were around 1,44155.

Comment: You can replace SELECT with  SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: Hi. "Merge" doesn't mean anything. What are you trying (but not bothering) to say? How do the result rows get constructed based on what rows are input? Please edit your question. (Notice that *your answer* (which I just noticed) contains this information that clearly is needed to answer the question--yet it isn't in the question, and if you had forced yourself to write clearly you would have come up with it before your question & probably not needed to ask it. Google 'rubber ducking'. See [ask]. PS When you've waited the minimum time you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me was that I had to add a unique identifier to each row on both the tables. The column rule and name were common to both the tables but both had redundant entries and I wanted to preserve the redundant data so I updated my tables with new id column.

T1:

> id,b_1,b_2,b_3,rule,name

T2:

> id,rule,name,a_1,a_2,a_3

The id column is NOT NULL and auto incremented.

Now I had a common unique column through which I can join both the table.

```
Select b.b_1, b.b_2, b.b_3, rule, name, a.a_1, a.a_2, a.a_3 from T1 b INNER JOIN T2 a ON b.id=a.id;
```

This query gave me the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

there are two conditions

1) if the two tables have relation of N-M(meaning that each item of table1 has M items in table2 and each item in table2 has N items in table1)

2) if the two tables have relation of 1-M(meaning that each item of table1 has M items in table2 and each item in table2 has  1 item in table1)

in case 1 you have to make another table using the combining columns of both table which in your case it's rule,name and for example lets call it **jointable** , then the tables would be like

table1(a1,a2,a3,rule,name)==>primary key(rule,name)

jointable(rule,name) ==> primary key(rule,name)

table2(b1,b2,b3,rule,name) ==>primary key(rule,name)

and the select statement would be

```
select table1.a1 ,table1.a2 ,table1.a3,table1.name,table1.rule,table2.b1,table2.b2,table2.b3
from jointable 
join table1 on table1.rule = jointable.rule and table1.name = jointable.name
join table2 on table2.rule = jointable.rule and table2.name = jointable.name
```

and

in case 2 one table contains primary key(like rule and name in table1) and the other table (like table2) contains foreign key referencing the parent table primary key which in this case would be rule,name of table1(note that table 1 is the parent and the child which is **table 2 cannot contain a value that the parent doesn't have**)

so tables would be like:

table1(a1,a2,a3,rule,name) ==>primary key(rule,name)

table2(b1,b2,b3,rule,name) ==>foreign key(rule,name) references table1(rule,name)

and the select statement would be like:

```
select table1.a1 ,table1.a2 ,table1.a3,table1.name,table1.rule,table2.b1,table2.b2,table2.b3
  from table1 join table2 on table1.name=table2.name and table1.rule=table2.rule
```